# Wouldn't this Greedy Algorithm achieve the highest possible of money in this situation?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, optimization, algorithms, recursive-algorithms

I am doing a practice question from  [Midterm Dynamic Programming](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/academic/class/15451-s10/www/midterm/mterm.pdf)

**The Problem** :
Consider a row of n numbers a1, ..., an. The numbers are all positive, and n is even. We play a
game against an opponent, alternating turns. In each turn, a player selects either the first or last
number, removes it from the row, and collects that much money.

For example, if the numbers are 1,2,3,4 , a possible game may look like:

1. Player A takes 4: row is 1,2,3.
2. Player B takes 3: row is 1,2.
3. Player A takes 1: row is 2.
4. Player B takes 2, game over.

Both players ended with a total amount of 5. Note that A could have done better.

(2 pts) Show an example where the greedy algorithm fails to achieve the highest possible amount of money.

The solution to this problem  [Greedy Sol](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/academic/class/15451-s10/www/midterm/mtermsol.pdf) used a solution list of number of [1,2,10,3]. However I would argue using the greedy algorithm, " In each turn, a player selects either the first or last" would work here to achieve the highest amount of money. Here is how I would work out the greedy algorithm

1. Player A takes 1: row is 2, 10, 3.
2. Player B takes 3: row is 2, 10.
3. Player A takes 2: row is 10.
4. Player B takes 10, game over.

And Player B has achieved the highest possible amount of money, 13.

Does everyone agree with my walkthrough and that the solution is wrong?

The solution I came up was 2, 8, 7, 6, 4. The idea I had here was that the highest amount of money could only be achieved by the player picking first(3 numbers).

For the player who picks first to achieve the highest possible amount of money. he or she would have to pick 8, 7, and 6. However with this greedy algorithm, that player in the first move either has to choose 2 or 4, meaning the highest possible amount of money is not achievable.(bc player 1 was the only player that could achieve the highest amount of money)

Comment: The greedy algorithm says "take the larger of first or last", so in that example, per the greedy algorithm, $A$ would first take $3$, making $10$ accessible to $B$. Taking either first or last is the rule of the game.

Comment: The point of the solution is that if A uses the greedy algorithm, A will not achieve the optimal payout.  Forget about B's strategy and payout.

Comment: @vadim123 Wouldn't you have to consider that A or B could achieve the optimal payout?

Comment: @DanielFischer So Just to make sure with [1, 2, 3, 4], the greedy algorithm will also not achieve the optimal payout?

Comment: For [1,2,3,4], the greedy algorithm works, if $B$ plays well, the $6$ that the greedy algorithm gives $A$ is optimal.

Comment: @DanielFischer How would it work though? Both A and B will take larger of first or last. A takes 4 and B takes 3. A sum of 7 is no longer achieveable by one player.

Comment: The "highest possible amount" is to be understood as "the highest possible amount when the opponent plays well", not as "the sum of the largest $\frac{n}{2}$ numbers". You could only get that in special configurations and when the opponent cooperates. In [7,5,1,2,3,4,8,6], you cannot get $5+6+7+8 = 26$, whatever $B$ does. On the first turn, $B$ _must_ take one of the largest four numbers.

Comment: Can you go back to the [1, 2, 3, 4] example? This new one is too confusing to me. So going off "the highest possible amount when the opponent plays well",  this means that both A and B will go for the larger of first and last. A would choose 4. B will choose 3. The highest possible amount of money wo greedy would be 4 + 3 = 7.(example alludes to this as well, A could have done better, meaning A theoretically could have gotten 7, not 5. Can you clarify this? Wouldn't this satisfy your requirement of both people playing well? Therefore greedy wouldn't work with [1, 2, 3, 4]?

Answer (score 1):

What happened here was, thanks to @DanielFischer comment, I confused the definition of greedy algorithm and the actual rules of the game.

A greedy algorithm is one that "looks for simple, easy-to-implement solutions to complex, multi-step problems by deciding which next step will provide the most obvious benefit." [Greedy 1 Def](http://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/greedy-algorithm) and doing so "without worrying about the effect these decisions may have in the future." [Greedy 2 Def](http://www.personal.kent.edu/~rmuhamma/Algorithms/MyAlgorithms/Greedy/greedyIntro.htm).

Based on those two definitions and the *rules* of the game, the greedy algorithm here would be "take the larger of first or last"(@DanielFischer's comment")

Working that greedy algorithm with an input of [1, 2, 10, 3], player A would first choose 3 and player B would then choose 10. Because 10 and 3 need to be chosen by the same player to reach the highest payment, the greedy algorithm fails to achieve the highest possible amount of money